# Why JMSProducer interface does not extend java.lang.Autocloseable?

Tags: java, jms, jms2

As per the JMS specs for classic APIs

```
The Connection, Session, MessageProducer, MessageConsumer and
QueueBrowser interfaces have been modified to extend the
java.lang.Autocloseable interface. This means that applications can
create these objects using a Java SE 7 try-with-resources statement which
removes the need for applications to explicitly call close() when these
objects are no longer required.
```

And after JMS2 for classic APIs

```
The new JMSContext and JMSConsumer interfaces also extend the
java.lang.Autocloseable interface.
```

Question is why JMSProducer not extend AutoCloseable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

last paragraph from javadoc of JMSProducer

> Instances of JMSProducer are intended to be lightweight objects which
>   can be created freely and which do not consume significant resources.
>   This interface therefore does not provide a close method.

yes it is confusing, but note that MessageProducer does implement Autocloseable,
but JMSProducer does not.